# Writing html in php

Tags: php

hi i want to write html in php like this

but i am getting this error. i have seen manay example but my problem is unsolved.

```
Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '}' in /home/a2277283/public_html/pages/home.php on line 12
```

my code

```
<?php if (!isset($_SESSION['email'])) {?>
        <h4>Login</h4>
        <form action="scripts/login.php" method="POST"id="login_form">
            <strong>Email:</strong><input type="text" name="user_email"/> <input type="submit" value="Login" name="submit"/>
        </form>
        <?php}?>
```

Comment: Check before elements. Class , if else or functions..

Comment: there should be a space    `<?php } ?>`

Comment: show full page code ...!!

Comment: For me the space between <?php and } on the last line worked

Comment: thanks miqdad ali. that was problem. and who vote me down for nothing?

Comment: post your full part of coding

Comment: It wasn't me, but I wouldn't say it was for _nothing_... the error you posted is fairly self-explanatory...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This works :

```
<?php if(!isset($_SESSION['email'])){ ?>
        <h4>Login</h4>
        <form action="scripts/login.php" method="POST"id="login_form">
            <strong>Email:</strong><input type="text" name="user_email"/> <input type="submit" value="Login" name="submit"/>
        </form>
<?php } ?>
```

space after `<?php`

Answer (score 2):

TRY ending with spaces

```
<?php } ?>
```

Answer (score 2):

When I run that code I get:

> Parse error: parse error in /Users/david/x.php on line 6

You need a space after the `<?php`. Then the code will run as expected and the `}` will be picked up.

Answer (score 1):

This syntax is a little bit tricky. I would suggest this one:

```
<?php if (true): ?>
    <p>Some html...</p>
<?php endif; ?>
```

Answer (score 1):

The error occured because of `<?php}?>`, it should be `<?php } ?>` (space after `php` is required).It's better to use `if(): endif;` when dealing with html withing `php` code, like

```
if(condition):
    // if passed true     
else:
    // if passed false
endif;
```

In this case, you can write

```
<?php if(!isset($_SESSION['email'])) : ?>
    <h4>Login</h4>
    <form action="scripts/login.php" method="POST"id="login_form">
        <strong>Email:</strong><input type="text" name="user_email"/> <input type="submit" value="Login" name="submit"/>
    </form>
<?php endif; ?>
```